# Re-setting Ubuntu, checking files

Tags: unity, compiz, configuration, gconf

Is there any way to check files in Ubuntu and reset config if there is something wrong? Some application that will go through the files and detects if they are in a good standing.

Comment: Which applications or related configurations do you want to set to Defaults , please specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check the integrity of files that came from deb packages, you can make use of the **/var/lib/dpkg/info/*.md5sums** files.

Verifying Unity files:

```
cd /
md5sum -c /var/lib/dpkg/info/unity*.md5sums
```

If you get an error just run `sudo apt-get --reinstall install <corrupted-package-name>` to reinstall the package.

Comment: It looks like there are no errors. Thank you for help

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about Unity you can try to execute `unity --reset` on a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T).

Comment: yeah that would help my broken compiz config .. but I want to check all files if they are working or no. Cause I dont wanna be surprised  once I want to play something or do something with Ubuntu and then system crashes into terminal with error messages like before ...

Comment: Thank you @Eric Carvalho. Does `unity --reset` command reset any changes made by compiz?

Comment: @PLANTROON yes it does.